# 2D Skier physics looks very artificial

Tags: unity, c#, physics, game-mechanics

I am creating a ski slalom game and I coded a new physics routine, because I was told the rigidbodies are pure "not overly good thing" to use by my boss. With my physics routine it indeed looks much better, but I have no idea how could I make the skier look less plastic. Which means I want to achieve similar level of control like in Skiing Yeti Mountain, because there the physics is quite enjoyable, though still arcade. Basically the requirements are that I need to set up acceleration, top speed and the amount of grip to use when turning, but it somehow bites me back

```
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector2 slopeDirection = -Vector2.up;


    var dt = Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    var dirVector = Vector2.zero;

    dirVector.x = Mathf.Cos( radianOrientation );
    dirVector.y = Mathf.Sin( radianOrientation );

    float actualAcceleration = Mathf.Abs(Vector2.Dot(dirVector, slopeDirection));
    actualAcceleration = Mathf.Lerp(maximumAcceleration, 0, actualAcceleration) * Mathf.Pow(maximumAcceleration, accelerationSmoothing);

    velocity.x += actualAcceleration * dirVector.x * dt;
    velocity.y += actualAcceleration * dirVector.y * dt;

    Vector2 velocityDirection = velocity;
    velocityDirection.Normalize();

    float actualFriction = Mathf.Abs(Vector2.Dot(dirVector, slopeDirection));
    actualFriction = Mathf.Lerp(minimumFriction, maximumFriction, actualFriction) * Mathf.Pow(actualFriction, frictionSmoothing);

    // Simulate friction
    velocity *= actualFriction;
    Debug.Log(velocity);

    if(!_isFinished)
    {
        this.transform.position += new Vector3(velocity.y, -velocity.x, 0);
    }
```

why it is overly odd is that when I turn to the side it has a very abrupt power loss and when I turn the skis to 45 degrees to the slope. how could I achieve that the skier will slow down when he turns his skis, but after a little while it will accelerate again like in Skiing Yeti Mountain?

[image]

Comment: I strongly suggest you link some kind of animated gif or movie file here for people to see what you mean, or you're going to have a hard time getting an answer as we have little insight into what "feel" you're getting (or not getting).

Comment: I added it now to the question

Comment: Have you considered to stop using friction and just move the character forward with a constant speed while the player only controls the direction?

Comment: yes, but I need to add friction, because he needs to slow down a bit when he turns

Comment: Looks like you have too much friction for stopping, and too much acceleration for the down hill.

Comment: this is the issue, that I have min/max grip (friction parameters) set to 0.1 already plus the frictionSmoothing is 0.1 already when recorded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a friction value of 0.98-0.99 is ideal in most cases. Try that as your `actualFriction` value to start with, adjusting it in increments of 0.005 or so, till you hit the sweet spot. Consider just how quickly that deficit is applied - we multiply by this factor 60 times per second. So keep close to 1.0.

Also eliminate use of `frictionSmoothing` until you have the aforementioned value closer to what you want. I fear this secondary factor is making things harder rather than simpler to fix, right now. In fact, get rid of those `Pow` statements altogether for now, and work it from there. I can almost guarantee that whatever problems you're having, `Pow` is quite literally compounding them.

Then gradually - step by step - work your formulae back to a sane solution.

Comment: in the end we removed the pows and added an if branch there and it is much better, but still no cigar. Hope we just need to play with params a lot

Comment: @Citrus, would you mind posting here your solution (the fixed code)?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will help, but maybe try scaling the game up or down, and re tweaking the physics. I was having problems setting physics variables in a 2D game I'm making because my game was so small that each unit in the game was relatively large, so I didn't have as much precision. Coulda been a fluke though; mixed with my beginner lvl programming skills.